# Analog Microphone with Raspberry PI

Tags: gpio, audio, pi-zero, analog-to-digital

I have an analog microphone like this one :[image: analog mic]

Is there a way to record audio from GPIOs and convert it to readable format, such as .mp3 or .wav ?

I searched on Google, but I didn't find what i want ... Everyone tell about buying an usb sound card or mic.

Comment: See also https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/43320/19949

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here.