# Using Raspberry Pi as audio filter

Tags: gpio, audio, pi-zero

So I work with many devices that produce static or other undesired noise and I want to use my raspberry pi zero to filter the static from the incoming audio and play it out of the HDMI audio device. I know how to use PulseAudio to filter a source and pump it into a sink. What I don't know is how to turn the GPIO pins into a 3.5mm "aux" jack.

Comment: Do you want to use GPIO as input or output? For input: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43320/raspberry-pi-3-audio-input

Comment: @Mark say I got the hat mentioned in the post. Would I use line in or mic in with, for example, my phone? Or would I need something different entirely to use with an "aux" cord?

Comment: AFAIK you should use line in because microphone produces much weaker signal and to compensate this, mic-in input comes to pre-amp first. And mic-in are usually mono.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Mark, I figured out I just need a GPIO audio card with a line in, then using an "aux" cord directly connect the line in and device.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Comment: @Ingo at the time it wouldn't let me and I had since forgotten the post. I've taken care of it now.

Comment: Thanks :-) Yes, the questioner has to wait two days before he can accept his own new answer.