# how to use a normal microphone instance of USB microphone in Raspberrypi 3b+

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-stretch

I want to recognize the voice using raspberry pi and for that required a microphone

but most of the cases I have seen that USB microphone used in Raspberrypi for voice input, but I want to use a normal two-wire capsule microphone to provide voice input for recognition of the voice. 
So I need help on this, Please suggest me how to interface a normal capsule microphone with raspberry pi for voice input to recognize the voice.

Thanks,

Comment: People use USB mics because the Pi has no analog inputs. The only other option is a soundcard

Comment: How about try Audio Converter, you can find it in Aliexpress for 1.9$
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32906368885.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.4e021542CZz7IV&algo_pvid=8b6c1b45-18fc-4f03-9c2a-5c8a3c704274&algo_expid=8b6c1b45-18fc-4f03-9c2a-5c8a3c704274-17&btsid=f8f5d47c-387c-4659-966c-3d6a1745d4c4&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0%2Csearchweb201602_6%2Csearchweb201603_52

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no audio input on the Raspberry 3B+.
You will have to find a hat to put your Piezo microphone, or go with USB…

It's difficult to make a Audio input as it requires a efficient and fast ADC to convert the signal and this is not something present on the Raspberry 3B+.

Note that USB may have latency compared to GPIO HAT based solutions.
But going USB allow you to reuse the device on a standard computer.

[Raspberry Pi 3 audio input?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43320/raspberry-pi-3-audio-input)

[Specs](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/raspberry-pi-3bplus-specs-benchmarks/)

Comment: No, I am not going to any USB interface for audio input which I had mentioned before. I need another solution.

Comment: Arnaud, can we use this i2c interface board for audio input for raspberry pi Adafruit Silicon MEMS Microphone Breakout - SPW2430 [ADA2716]   link:   https://thepihut.com/products/adafruit-silicon-mems-microphone-breakout-spw2430?ref=isp_rel_prd&isp_ref_pos=1

Comment: No as said in my answer you will need an ADC to transform your voice into digital data. And then you will need to collect the data.
What you showed me is just a microphone breakout board. No amplificator (could be good to have) and no chip to turn voice into precious bits.

Example : https://www.seeedstudio.com/ReSpeaker-2-Mics-Pi-HAT.html

Comment: Hi Arnaud, I need another suggestion from you. Like we have 4 channel USB port in raspberry pi now if I remove any two USB and therefrom if I hook up the 4 wire with USB input microphone. is that possible to communicate as before like USB?   Actually the main motive is there should not be any flexible(easy Removeable )input communication that's why I just wanted to convert port to wire communication any how.

Comment: Hi, If your microphone is USB, I believe you can plug it this way. But I'm not sure of understanding your question..